# Can we save wire on this circuit Conditional Probability?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

**This question is regarding Conditional Probability + Bayes.**
Circuit with the operational probability of the elements is attached.

I got the answer for probability that the electricity will flow from the circuit A to B as: = 0.788 (Hope this is correct)

Part of the question ask following.

> Is it possible to save wire that connects the elements without
> affecting functionality of the network? Explain which part of wiring
> can be removed.

How could we answer the above question. Is that the wire which directly connects e1 to B? But the working probability of e1 to B (0.5) is higher than e1 to e4 to B (0.5 * 0.8 = 0.4)

Please provide a clue on answering this part.

In the attached image, starting point is A. Circuit is consisting with 3 elements (e1, e2, e3) attached parallelly. And to that, e4 is attached. e1 has a direct wiring to the end-B as well.
Operational Probabilities of each element.
P(e1) = 0.5;
P(e2) = 0.2;
P(e3) = 0.3;
P(e4) = 0.8;

[Circuit with Probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hPhc.jpg)

Comment: I think your result for the probability is wrong. If you show how you calculated that, we could point out the error – I suspect that understanding that error would help you solve the second part of the question.

Comment: P=[[P(e1)∪P(e2)∪P(e3)]∩P(e4)]∪P(e1)

Comment: =1−([1−[(1−(P(e1 ′ )∗P(e2 ′ )∗P(e3 ′ )))∗P(e4)]]∗P(e1 ′ ))  = 1 - ( [ 1 - [( 1 - (0.5*0.8*0.7)) * 0.8 ]] * 0.5 )

Comment: @joriki above comments mentioned how I calculated the probability. Did I do it wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation as shown in the comments is wrong because in the outermost multiplication you apply the multiplication rule, which holds for independent events, to events that are dependent because $e_1$ appears in both of them. This gives you an indication which wire can be removed: It’s the one that causes this dependence, that involves $e_1$ in the first factor even though the probability that the system conducts because of $e_1$ is already fully accounted for in the second factor.